# Run exported Google Cloud Data Fusion pipeline

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-data-fusion

I have exported a Cloud Data Fusion pipeline. How can i trigger the job on a cluster whenever I want?
I tried to find it in the documentation but couldn't get anywhere.

Comment: Can you clarify. Did you mean importing instead of exporting a pipeline to CDF? If exported, where is the target pipeline deployed?

Comment: Apologies, for some reason my previous answer got deleted without a notification on why it was deleted. Could you elaborate a little bit on your question? Do you want to trigger it manually, via a script, a schedule? Is it guaranteed that the Data Fusion instance will be up and running when you want to trigger the pipeline?